# The overall voltage gain in the circuit is not matching my simulation result. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bjt, voltage-divider

The overall voltage gain in the circuit is not matching my simulation result, but all other calculations of the circuit is almost the same. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK how did you arrive at those bizarrely small coupling capacitor values??? Is this supposed ho be a high pass filter? What ARE the specifications (including bandwidth)? If you set them all to 0.1 uF do you get results closer to your expectations?

Comment: The input to the amplifier is current, not voltage, is that on purpose? Also, which stage has the problem? What the gain is supposed to be? Also, your resistor and capacitor values are quite absurd, you can't buy those components in real life. There are resistors with three significant digits, sure, but your circuit is not realizable if it depends on tens of kilo-ohm resistances specified with 1 ohm accuracy, and capacitors specified with 0.1 femtofarad accuracy.

Comment: What did you assume for the \$\beta\$ of the NPN transistors in your hand calculation?

Comment: Why do you have capacitor values like 196.7734pF? That makes no sense. Convince me why 200 pF doesn't suffice. Also a gain of 39.029 dB is **purely theoretical**. Even accurate resistors have 1% tolerance, transistors can have 50% tolerance on \$\beta\$. So 39 dB gain is more than accurate enough. In the real world you would be lucky to get that gain within 2 dB of the designed value. When an **accurate** gain is needed circuit designers use **feedback** to determine the gain properly. You will learn about that later so forget that for now.

Comment: Design Specifications
1. Power supply, V_CC = 13V
2. Power consumption < 2mW
3. Overall voltage gain, A_(V(tot)) > 60dB
4. Output driving load: 212Ω resistive load 15pF capacitive load
5. Input frequency = 100kHz

Comment: i use the exact values from my calculations to simulate..thats why i didnt used 200pF

Comment: Crap. There's no global NFB. Not even worth the trouble to consider.

Comment: For  = 200...

Comment: I changed the current source to voltage source and the problem is fixed i think..i got 20% difference from calculation value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0% chance your simulation will match reality.   Real components have tolerances, significant  especially for caps and transistors.   I'm surprised you got as close as you did.

Comment: Haha, yeah those are really close. I WISH I could consistently under 10%, let alone having 5% as my high end deviation 5% with it normally being half or a quarter of that.